# How can i get Exact position of a TextView on a imageview

Tags: android

I am designing a screen in which i need to get the exact position of the TextView on a image. Is there any way to get position of That TextView on ImageView?

Comment: You cannot have a TextView inside a ImageView since ImageView is not a ViewGroup instance such as LinearLayout, FrameLayout etc.

Comment: If you are taking one parent layout for eg. Relativelayout and Taking Imageview and Textview as chil of that parent. and overlapping that textview on Imageview you will get the view as you want but if we talk about the postion i guess the position could be got based on paren Here the parent is RelativaLayout not the Imageview.

Comment: thanx for reply.. So is there any way to get position of that textview Under RelativeLayout?

Comment: For a position relative to the parent just use getLeft() and getTop().

Answer (score 0):

This will set textview on imageview by setting same width and height parameter.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" /></FrameLayout>
```